# Extract all numbers from string

Tags: c#, regex, numbers

Let's say I have a string such as `123ad456`. I want to make a method that separates the groups of numbers into a list, so then the output will be something like `123,456`.

I've tried doing `return Regex.Match(str, @"-?\d+").Value;`, but that only outputs the first occurrence of a number, so the output would be `123`. I also know I can use `Regex.Matches`, but from my understanding, that would output `123456`, not separating the different groups of numbers.

I also see from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.7.2) page on MSDN that `Regex.Match` has an overload that takes the `string` to find a match for and an `int` as an index at which to search for the match, but I don't see an overload that takes in the above in addition to a parameter for the regex pattern to search for, and the same goes for `Regex.Matches`.

I guess the approach to use would be to use a `for` loop of some sort, but I'm not entirely sure what to do. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [`Regex.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to to use `Matches` instead of `Match`. Then simply iterate over all matches:

```
string result = "";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(str, @"-?\d+"))
{
    result += match.result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may iterate over string data using foreach and use `TryParse` to check each character.

```
foreach (var item in stringData)
{
    if (int.TryParse(item.ToString(), out int data))
    {
        // int data is contained in variable data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of `string.Join` and `Regex.Matches`:

```
string result = string.Join(",", Regex.Matches(str, @"-?\d+").Select(m => m.Value));
```

`string.Join` performs better than continually appending to an existing string.

Answer (score -1):

\d+ is the regex for integer numbers;

//System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, @"\d+").Value;
returns a string with the very first occurence of a number in subjectString.

Int32.Parse(resultString) will then give you the number.

Comment: The question specifically asks for all matches, not just the first. Getting all matches is the focus of the question, and your answer doesn't address it at all.

Comment: Also, you're not handling signed numbers.